# struts spring integration get following error java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.struts.ContextLoaderPlugIn

Tags: spring

In my application i used spring-struts.jar but it is throwing this error.

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.struts.ContextLoaderPlugIn
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1714)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1559)
    at org.apache.struts.util.RequestUtils.applicationClass(RequestUtils.java:207)
    at org.apache.struts.util.RequestUtils.applicationInstance(RequestUtils.java:231)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.initModulePlugIns(ActionServlet.java:1142)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.init(ActionServlet.java:473)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1280)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1088)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5123)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5407)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Comment: Looks like `spring-struts` is missing in your classpath.

Comment: spring-struts.jar in present in configure-Build-path.

Comment: Also in runtime classpath? And you need org.springframework.web.struts-3.x.x.RELEASE.jar if you use spring 3

Comment: I am using spring 2 jars

Comment: struts1 is no more supported since spring4.x 

see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27709352/how-long-will-spring-3-x-continue-to-be-supported

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the **spring-web** and **spring-web-struts** jars. `ContextLoaderPlugIn` class is part of `spring-web-struts` jar. And make sure they are added to your classpath.

Comment: I added both spring-web and spring-web-struts jar in configure-build-path.

Comment: Put some of your code here. Your all configuration related files. Then only someone can help.