# How long will Spring 3.x continue to be supported?

Tags: spring, spring-3

I've recently inherited a project that's built on some older technologies, including iBATIS 2.x, and Struts 1.x. Both of those seem to be supported (though @Deprecated) in Spring 3.2.x, and not at all in Spring 4.x:

- [`org.springframework.orm.ibatis`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/orm/ibatis/package-summary.html), [Object Relational Mapping (ORM) Data Access - iBATIS SQL Maps](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/orm.html#orm-ibatis)
- [`org.springframework.web.struts`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/struts/package-summary.html), [Integrating with other web frameworks - Apache Struts 1.x and 2.x](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/web-integration.html#struts)

However, before I start the effort of migrating to Spring 3, I want to know how much longer I can expect to see it supported by the upstream developers. Would I have enough time to keep running Spring 3 while I migrate other parts of my application to newer tools, and then finally migrate over to Spring 4? Or should I focus on upgrading all of these other things before I can get onto Spring?

Comment: With Spring 4.2 in the making I expect support for the 3.2.x branch to stop quite soon. The normal schedule is to support the latest version (4.1) and the one before that (4.0). However in the case, due to the popularity of the 3.2 version, they decided to support 3.2 a little longer.

Comment: This should have been an answer, I think? Do you have a link to where "they" give this policy, or for how much longer they plan to support 3.2?

Comment: There was once a forum post/announcement about the support schedule for newer release (about 6 years ago). In a recent comment on the release of Spring 4.1 they added the notion of still supporting Spring 3.2.

Comment: [This](http://spring.io/blog/2014/12/30/spring-framework-4-1-4-4-0-9-3-2-13-released) release message sheds some light on the lifetime of the 3.2.x branch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Spring 3.X will be end-of-life as of Dec 31 2016](https://spring.io/blog/2015/06/15/spring-framework-3-2-x-eol-on-dec-31-2016), but there will only be maintenance releases until that time (no feature development will happen).

Comment: While I found @Gert-Jan to have the most useful answer for what I *really* wanted to know, your answer most accurately answers my posted question. Thanks for following up.

Answer (score 2):

I hardly understand your problem. iBATIS 2.x and Struts 1.x are both no longer supported. They can work fine, as does Spring 2.x, but if a security problem is discovered, it will not be fixed.

If you contemplate migrating to Spring 3.x, you should also contemplate the migration to MyBatis and Struts 2.x (or Spring MVC ?) unless you have special requirements.

BTW, Spring 3.0 and 3.1 series are no longer supported either, and support for 3.2 should end when 4.2 will reach General Availability status, as Spring Framework generally offers support for current version, and the 2 previous (legacy) ones.

Comment: Basically, I'm trying to avoid adding yet-another unsupported library out of the gate. I know iBATIS 2.x and Struts 1.x are unsupported, but I see Spring as a possible tool for me to use to migrate to better solutions. But if I then have to immediately turn around and rewrite a lot of the Spring code to move to 4.x, it seems like it'd be better to first put the effort into upgrading those other libraries.

Comment: @pioto IMHO, the harder part will be Struts1 because Struts2 is a completely different product. As you use Struts1 and iBATIS, I suppose you only use Spring for dependency injection and maybe AOP. AFAIK, there is a lot of compatibility in core Spring Framework, and all you will write for Spring 3 should work in Spring 4.

Comment: right now, this project doesn't use Spring at all. I'd like it to, though, and I also want it to get off of Struts 1 entirely. Same for getting off of iBATIS. It seems like migrating to Struts2 and to MyBatis are not trivial tasks, so I'm also contemplating doing a gradual migration to Hibernate and Spring MVC. The code base is too large for me to do a quick conversion all at once...

Answer (score 0):

I just work on project that uses Spring 4 with MyBatis. There is project [MyBatis-Spring](https://mybatis.github.io/spring/) that integrates these two. Works like charm.

Don't know how to help with second bullet, cause we are using Spring MVC.

Comment: OP's project uses the older iBATIS 2.x, not MyBatis 3.x.

Comment: You will need to migrate to newer version iBatis/MyBatis anyway. MyBatis wiki: "MyBatis is a fork of iBATIS 3.0 and is maintained by a team that includes the original creators of iBATIS."

Comment: Yes, I know I'll have to migrate off of iBatis to MyBatis (or something else entirely); my goal is to figure out which problem I need to tackle first.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that they've just posted a blog post that includes clarification on this topic:

> Furthermore, please note that the 3.2.x line - and therefore the
>   entire 3.x generation - is approaching its end of life in 2015. We are
>   still committed to basic maintenance for critical issues; however,
>   don’t expect more than two or three further 3.2.x releases down the
>   road.

Source: [Spring Framework 4.1.4 & 4.0.9 & 3.2.13 released](http://spring.io/blog/2014/12/30/spring-framework-4-1-4-4-0-9-3-2-13-released)

So, it seems that I'd have at least a few months of 3.x being supported to work on transitioning everything.

Answer (score 0):

For my current project I'm required to use Struts 1.2.4. But I also wanted to utilize Spring 4.1.x.

To compensate for the missing Struts support since Spring 4, I copied the code from the [spring-struts 3.2.13](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/tree/v3.2.13.RELEASE/spring-struts) package and created a Spring 4.1.5 compatible [spring-struts-forwardport](http://github.com/Gert-Jan1966/spring-struts-forwardport) package.

Obviously this is not the most elegant solution, but maybe this can help you solve your problem.

I guess this package will also work with the next Spring 4.1 releases.

Comment: Thanks. I think I may want to go with this approach, rather than continuing to build new code on top of Spring 3.2.x, only to have to upgrade it again later. Any chance you'd be willing/able to package your work so that it's available on Maven Central?